# How to keep a relay closed until electricity is given again

Tags: relay

I send current through relay to turn on relay. I want to keep relay turned on even after i stop current flow. Then again when i send current the relay should close.

If i send current through relay, the bulb should light. Then i stop current through relay and the buld should stay light. Then after some time when i send current through the relay again, then the buld must be turned off. Any ideas?

Comment: Google latching relays

Comment: I think you better provide some type of schematic and state diagram so as to better show what you have schemed up. When you say "send current through" it is not clear if you refer to the relay coil, contacts or both.

Comment: There are two types . Single coil with bipolar pulses to set/Reset or dual coils with unipolar set/Reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 1-coil latching relay combined with a h-bridge IC to manage the set/rest of the latching relay.

You only need to send a short 30 to 50 millisecond pulse to the latching relay to cause it to switch states. It will remain in that state until you pulse it again in the opposite direction.

The h-bridge provides a convenient way to reverse the current flow needed across the single coil and provides logic compatible GPIO interfaces if you need to connect to an MCU.

Answer (score 3):

**Latching Relays**

> Latching relays have a small metal strip that, in essence, revolves
>   between two terminals. Solenoids, or small coils of wire, can be found
>   on either side of a magnetized switch that has one input and two
>   outputs at these terminals. The switch can be used to toggle one
>   circuit on and off, or it can be used to switch power between two
>   circuits. It's the coils that control the relay action. When an
>   electrical flow goes into the coils, that current generates a magnetic
>   field which turns off. The magnetic strip between the two coils is
>   also exposed to the magnetic field, so that when the circuit causes a
>   pulse of electrical current through these coils, it then pushes the
>   switch mechanism from side to side. The metal strip remains in that
>   position until it receives another magnetic pulse, but this time in
>   the opposite direction. This action will push the switch back to the
>   other terminal. This type of relay remains in the last position it was
>   in when the current was removed.

---

This is another possibility depending on application type:
[Case](http://i1106.photobucket.com/albums/h369/mojoatomic/latching_animation_zpsz61m6bzo.gif)

Comment: Latching relays it is